# SpringBoot tables only joining in the endpoint they are posted (Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, hibernate, rest

Sorry if I had trouble explaining my problem. I'm new to Spring Boot and I've been having trouble for some time now.

What happens is the following: I have this two classes:

**Class Character**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="characters")
public class Character {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "character_sequence",
            sequenceName = "character_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "character_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean is_alive;
    private String role;
    private int first_appearance_manga;
    private int first_appearance_anime;
    private URL char_image;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stands_id")
    private List<Stand> stands;
```

**Class Stand**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="stands")
public class Stand {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "stand_sequence",
            sequenceName = "stand_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "stand_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private URL image_link;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> type;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> abilities;
    @OneToOne(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "stand_stats_id")
    private StandStats stats;

    @ManyToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "characters_id")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Character character;
```

The post seems to work fine, but the table relation is only done in the endpoint it is posted in.

Example posting on http://localhost:8080/api/v1/characters

Characters endpoint

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Kujo Jotaro",
"age": 17,
"is_alive": true,
"role": "Protagonist",
"first_appearance_manga": 114,
"first_appearance_anime": 1,
"char_image": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg",
"stands": [
{
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Star Platinum",
     "image_link": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg",
     "type": [
        "Ability 1",
        "Ability 2"
      ],
    "abilities": [
        "Ability 1",
        "Ability 2"
      ],
     "stats": {
       "id": 1,
       "destructivePower": "A",
       "speed": "A",
       "range": "C",
       "persistence": "A",
       "precision": "A",
       "developmentalPotential": "A"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

This is shown fine. However, when accessing
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stand

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Star Platinum",
"image_link": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg",
"type": [
"Ability 1",
"Ability 2"
],
"abilities": [
"Ability 1",
"Ability 2"
],
"stats": {
"id": 1,
"destructivePower": "A",
"speed": "A",
"range": "C",
"persistence": "A",
"precision": "A",
"developmentalPotential": "A"
}
}
]
```

As you can see, there's no character in stand, when in my classes and post request I specified both.

POST request I used here:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Star Platinum",
  "image_link": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg",
  "type": [
    "Ability 1",
    "Ability 2"
  ],
  "abilities": [
    "Ability 1",
    "Ability 2"
  ],
  "stats": {
    "id": 1,
    "destructivePower": "A",
    "speed": "A",
    "range": "C",
    "persistence": "A",
    "precision": "A",
    "developmentalPotential": "A"
  },
  "character": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Kujo Jotaro",
    "age": 17,
    "is_alive": true,
    "role": "Protagonist",
    "first_appearance_manga": 114,
    "first_appearance_anime": 1,
    "char_image": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg"
  }
}
```

**The oppposite happens when posting on**
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stand, where the result is

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Star Platinum",
    "image_link": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg",
    "type": [
      "Ability 1",
      "Ability 2"
    ],
    "abilities": [
      "Ability 1",
      "Ability 2"
    ],
    "stats": {
      "id": 1,
      "destructivePower": "A",
      "speed": "A",
      "range": "C",
      "persistence": "A",
      "precision": "A",
      "developmentalPotential": "A"
    },
    "character": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Kujo Jotaro",
      "age": 17,
      "is_alive": true,
      "role": "Protagonist",
      "first_appearance_manga": 114,
      "first_appearance_anime": 1,
      "char_image": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg",
      "stands": []
    }
  }
]
```

**http://localhost:8080/api/v1/characters result:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Kujo Jotaro",
    "age": 17,
    "is_alive": true,
    "role": "Protagonist",
    "first_appearance_manga": 114,
    "first_appearance_anime": 1,
    "char_image": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg",
    "stands": []
  }
]
```

**Post request used here**:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Kujo Jotaro",
  "age": 17,
  "is_alive": true,
  "role": "Protagonist",
  "first_appearance_manga": 114,
  "first_appearance_anime": 1,
  "char_image": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg",
  "stands": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Star Platinum",
      "image_link": "https://i.imgur.com/ykdyYlu.jpeg",
      "type": [
        "Ability 1",
        "Ability 2"
      ],
      "abilities": [
        "Ability 1",
        "Ability 2"
      ],
      "stats": {
        "id": 1,
        "destructivePower": "A",
        "speed": "A",
        "range": "C",
        "persistence": "A",
        "precision": "A",
        "developmentalPotential": "A"
      }
    }
  ],

}
```

**I want to be able to post in one and see the relation between the tables in both endpoints instead of in the one being posted**. I've tried many things. I messed with the annotations, tried to change the query, but nothing seems to work.

If any more code is needed please tell me and I will add everything necessary. Huge thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake. You need to map the entities both ways to make it work so, usually, it is an issue when using DTOs as DBOs.

Spring will not map them for you so you need to loop through the stans and add the "parent" Character to each of them and vice-versa. All your mappings need to be set (not null) before saving to Hibernate.

Comment: This mapping should be done in the model classes or in services/controllers/other logic classes?

Comment: Doesn't really matter but logically, I usually convert my DTOs to DBOs in controller if there is no logic and service if there is. If it is something (i.e. multiple endpoints using same DTOs and DBOs) that you need to do often, a helper class is also a good idea.